# What exactly are anonymous functions?

Tags: ruby, anonymous-function

In my journey of a thousand lines of Ruby, I'm having a really hard time with the concept of anonymous functions. Wikipedia [says something about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_functions) there being some nameless soul in the code and it submitting to a higher order, but my understanding ends there.

Or in other words, how would I (when I understand it) explain anonymous functions to my mom?

Comment: Is "anonymous function" a term more often used in the Perl community?

Comment: And the javascript community.  And you'd call them lambda expressions in lisp/scheme.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An anonymous function has these characteristics:

1. It has no name (hence anonymous)
2. Is defined inline
3. Used when you don't want the overhead/formality of a normal function
4. Is not explicitly referenced more than once, unless passed as an argument to another function

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by _"is not explicitly referenced more than once"_? It does not seem correct to me. For example: `x = lambda{ ... }; def bar(y); @opts={callback:y}; end; bar(x)` There are now two references to the function, and could easily be three if `bar` creates any closures. Why do you suggest that these references somehow make this lambda no longer an 'anonymous function'?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by _"is defined inline"_? What would be an example of something not _"defined inline"_ (but matching your other criteria) that makes it no longer an _"anonymous function"_?

Comment: By inline I mean use the anonymous function as an argument or defined within the body of another function etc. Non-inline would be a typical function.

Comment: 4 is wrong. They only start making sense when they are referenced more than once, like blocks can be in smalltalk.

Comment: I'm not familiar with smalltalk, but how do you reference an anonymous function if it has no name?

Comment: @sym3tri: Once you pass a function as a parameter to another function, that other function can pass it to other functions, and so on. The anonymous function can be referenced (used) as many times as you want.

Answer (score 13):

Here's one example of an anonymous function in Ruby (called a *block* in this case):

```
my_array.each{ |item| puts item }
```

Where's the anonymous function in the above? Why, it's the one that receives a single parameter, names it 'item', and then prints it. In JavaScript, the above might be written as...

```js
Array.prototype.each = function(anon){
  for (var i=0,len=this.length;i<len;++i) anon(this[i]);
};
myArray.each(function(item){ console.log(item); });
```

...which both makes it a little bit more clear that a function is being passed as an argument, and also helps one appreciate Ruby's syntax. :)

Here's another anonymous function (back in Ruby):

```
def count_to(n)
  puts "I'm going to count to #{n}"
  count = lambda do |i|
    if (i>0)
      count[i-1]
      puts i
    end
  end
  count[n]
  puts "I'm done counting!"
end
count_to(3)
#=> I'm going to count to 3
#=> 1
#=> 2
#=> 3
#=> I'm done counting!
```

Although the example is obviously contrived, it shows how you can create a new function (in this case named *count*) and assign it to a variable, and use that for recursive calls inside a master method. (Some feel that this is better than creating a second method just for the recursion, or re-using the master method for recursion with very different parameters.)

The function doesn't have a name, the variable does. You could assign it to any number of variables, all with different names.

Returning to the first example, there's even a syntax in Ruby for passing a lambda as the single, blessed block:

```
print_it = lambda{ |item| puts item }
%w[a b c].each(&print_it)
#=> a
#=> b
#=> c
```

...but you can also pass a lambda as a normal parameter and call it later, as illustrated here:

```
module Enumerable
  def do_both_to_each( f1, f2 )
    each do |item|
      f1[item]
      f2[item]
    end
  end
end

print_prefix  = lambda{ |i| print "#{i}*#{i} -> " }
print_squared = lambda{ |i| puts i*i }

(1..4).do_both_to_each(print_prefix,print_squared)
#=> 1*1 -> 1
#=> 2*2 -> 4
#=> 3*3 -> 9
#=> 4*4 -> 16
```

Answer (score 6):

In addiction to previous answers, the anonymous functions are very usefull when you working with [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29):

```
def make_adder n
  lambda { |x|
    x + n
  }
end

t = make_adder 100
puts t.call 1
```

Or (in Ruby 1.9):

```
def make_adder_1_9 n
   ->(x) {
     x + n
   }
end

t_1_9 = make_adder_1_9 100
puts t_1_9.call 1
```

Comment: In your 1.9 example, you might just as well use the syntax sugar for `call`: `t_1_9.(1)`.

Comment: ...in 1.8 and 1.9 lambdas also may be invoked via `t_1_9[1]` _(which is both shorter than either `.call` or `.()` and, in my opinion, more aesthetically pleasing)_.

Answer (score 4):

Just as Wikipedia says: a function with no name.

It means that you cannot invoke the function in the typical way, by using its name and parameters. Rather the function itself is usually a parameter to another function. A function that operates on functions is called a "higher order function".

Consider this JavaScript(I know you tagged this ruby but...):

```
  window.onload=function(){
           //some code here
  }
```

The function will execute when the page loads, but you cannot invoke it by name, because it does not have a name.

Comment: +1 Also, since you're asking about ruby, the anonymous ruby functions are called lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

## What is the point of an anonymous method?

#### Explanation by Analogy:

When I order my favourite burger (a greasy Big Nac), I don't want to spend 5 minutes filling out a formal order application: name, address, phone number etc. I ain't got time for that. I want to use my mouth: "give me a burger", nice and quick and easy.

Anonymous methods are kinda like the same thing, except when coding:

#### It's kinda like throwaway method allowing you to code faster

It's the same when coding. If you have to define a function, you have to put it somewhere (else), you have to call it something, and that's a pain, especially if you know you'll never, ever need it again. And when you read the code, you might have to use a complicated IDE to find that method again, and a reference to it. What a pain! You need a throwaway method that you can write directly in your code, where you need it, and just get it done, and move one. Anonymous methods solve this particular problem.

Answer (score -2):

Anonymous functions have the following characteristics:

- No name
- Inline declaration
- Executed directly when declared

Comment: Almost all of these points have already been brought up in more detail in the accepted answer.